# Help with SQL and table optimization

Tags: sql

I have two things to do: optimize table, write a query.

```
customer
id    customer    year_in_business   is_discountable   customers_friend_id 
1     a           2                  true              2
2     b           3                  false             1
3     c           2                  true              1
4     d           3                  true              null
```

Here customer_friend_id is pointing back to pk(id) of the same table.

```
product 
id   product 
1     xxx
2     yyy
3     aaaa

customer_product
customer_id  product_id
1             2
2             3
3             1
```

#### Questions

1. How to make these tables flexible or extensible in the future?
2. Get Name of each customer that has a friend and the name of that customer’s friend.

Comment: What have you attempted so far for the query?

Comment: sid You can press the `{}` to format your code blocks. I took care of it for you

Comment: Give it some thought .. what happens if a customer has more than one friend? What if the customer spans more than one year in business? The q is trying to get you thinking about normalisation IMHO.

Comment: Smells like homework....

Comment: @sid, please make the effort to use proper grammar, spelling, and to format your code. Editing tools are available in a toolbar above the text field when you ask a question. There is also edit help in a panel to the right.

Comment: this is not a home work i am a junior programmer in a small company trying to get things done .

Comment: @Sid - so back to my original comment, what have you attempted so far?

Comment: thanks nonnb . so i have to make a another table for customer_friends just like customer_product and i did not understand the What if the customer spans more than one year in business? i just named the column wrong years_in_bussiness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one suggestion: remove `customer.customers_friend_id` and create a new `CustomerFriend` table like so:

```
CustomerFriend
customerFriendID  customerID  friendID
1                 1           2
2                 2           1
3                 3           1
```

This will allow customers with more than one friend, and avoids nulls for customers without friends.